# SiteURL for SharePoint

Tags: web-part, web

I have developed a custom web part. This has got the site URL to set in the runtime based upon the Alternate Access Method i.e (Intranet or Extranet). So Site URL will change automatically based upon the context. But, most of the links in the web parts are needs to be hotcoded as we dont have context when they load for first time. Hence, all the links are unable to open and web part is not working as it does not know what is the SiteURL to load. Please suggest me a way to keep the state of the siteURL when they load for first time.

Comment: Where is the links pointing? Can't you use server relativer urls to get around this issue?

Comment: links are pointing to the lists of sharepoint. Basically, I can not see the web part it self.

Comment: Are those lists on the same web? If so, then you can make the links relative

Comment: Yes they are. Already all the links are relative.

Comment: If you do not have access to SPContext you are probably trying to render your content to early in the ASPX lifecycle. Try rendering the content in the Render event